# Port forwarding not working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, port-forwarding

I created a website in IIS 7.5 with a port of 50100. I can hit http://localhost:50100 and the site comes up in the browser. However, when I type  IP:port (IP of the router) into a web browser from outside the network, the site does not come up (time out). For port forwarding, I have 50100 for Port From and Port To, and the same internal IP (the server) as for the other functioning forwards. Should both Port From and Port To be 50100? Anything else I can check?

Comment: is the server firewall on and configured? On the firewall where you entered the port forward, is there an ACL you may need to change?

Comment: @uSlackr Ha! That was it! If you write your reply as an Answer, I'll mark it as THE Answer. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check.
Is the server firewall on and configured to allow this port? 
On the firewall where you entered the port forward, is there an ACL you may need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Your router has 2 IP addresses - internal, or local network, and external.
Local address is something like 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1
External address is different. Let's say it is 199.199.11.12 - just a random IP address for purpose of examples.

Your computer is in the local network with your router. Your computer has IP in that local network - something for example like 192.168.1.10. You must make sure that your computer has the same IP address reserved for it (for example if router is Wi-Fi it usually assings random IP address, unless you specify reservation).

You need to create a route on the router that will state that all requests to External_IP_ADDRESS:PORT1 will be redirected to YOUR_COMPUTER_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS:PORT2

Port2 is 50100 as you said
Port1 can be 80 - default for http connections

So, in this example the rule should be

199.199.12.12 : 80 redirected to 192.168.1.10 : 50100

that way if you open in browser http://199.199.12.12/ that request will go to your website.

If you have domain name - you need to set it up in IIS.
PS: some routers already have a rule for EXTERNAL_IP:80 - for their admin panel, in that case setup your router admin panel to open on :8080 or smth like that.

Comment: Actually, I want incoming requests from port 80 to go to the default website. I then want IP:50100 to go to a second website and 50200 to a third website, and so on.

Comment: Add routes in the router. It is all there. And setup IIS to recognize virtual hosts by port number.